# Android App Development Help : Perform Action as soon as data is entered

Tags: android

I had seen an Application on Android where as soon as a person enters anything into a textbox, the other text box that shows the output changes automatically without a need to press any button or anything. I wanted to know how to do that for an Android Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by adding [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to EditText . perform all operations on data entered by user in `afterTextChanged` because this method called when user stop typing in Edittext

```
EditText edttext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext);
edttext.addTextChangedListener(textChecker);
    TextWatcher textChecker = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  //set text to other Views 
     }

    };
```

see [this](http://www.cybernetikz.com/blog/android-textwatcher-example/) example for how we use TextWatcher

Answer (score 0):

You can `addTextChangedListener` to your EditText and use `onTextChanged` function to change the text in other EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Here ed is EditText ,I think ,this code done your expectation..just try this code

```
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int end) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //tv.setText(s.toString());
        if(s.length()==1){
                String get=s.toString();
             tv.setText(s.toString());
             tv.startAnimation(mytrans);
             mytrans.reset();
            }else if(s.length()==2){
                tv1.setText(s.subSequence(1,2));
                 tv1.startAnimation(myanim);
            }else if(s.length()==3){
                tv2.setText(s.subSequence(2, 3));
                tv2.startAnimation(mytrans);
            }else if(s.length()==4){
                tv3.setText(s.subSequence(3, 4));
                tv3.startAnimation(myalpha);
        }else if(s.length()==5){
            tv4.setText(s.subSequence(4, 5));
            tv4.startAnimation(myanim1);
        }else{
            tv.setText(s.toString());

                    ObjectAnimator animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv,"translationX",180);
                    animation2.setDuration(2000);
                    animation2.start();
                    ObjectAnimator animation3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv,"translationY",100);
                    animation3.setDuration(2000);
                    animation3.start();
                    ObjectAnimator animation4 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv,"rotation",360);
                    animation4.setDuration(2000);
                    animation4.start();
                    ib.startAnimation(myanim);
                    ib1.startAnimation(myanim1);
                    tv.startAnimation(mytrans); 
        }
            /*if(s.length()==6){
                ib.requestFocus();
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int end,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*ib.startAnimation(myanim);
            ib1.startAnimation(myanim1);
            tv.startAnimation(mytrans); */



        }
    });
```